# how can I test ios app for push notifications with distribution profile/certificate?

Tags: ios, push-notification, ssl-certificate, distribution, provisioning-profile

Push notifications in my app work fine with development profile/certificate, but I can't be sure if it's gonna work with distribution profile/certificate. How can I test it ?

Answer (score 2):

Ad hoc profile > Archive. > Run in your debug device > You get Adhoc device token.

Your push server should send with production APNS .cer & related private key (.p12):

1. Adhoc device token.
2. Your message
   to production APNS.

:)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create production APN certificate for the server side and build application with distribution profile.

Comment: That's what I've already done. I'm not asking how to do that, but how to test if it works. Anyway, I think I've found a solution - create ad hoc profile, archive the app with this profile, then save it as .ipa to disk, and then drag this file to itunes and sync.

Comment: may i know can you able to test the above solution? Please let me know its working or not..